# extrapolating data with numpy/python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

Let's say I have a simple data set. Perhaps in dictionary form, it would look like this:

`{1:5, 2:10, 3:15, 4:20, 5:25}`

(the order is always ascending).
What I want to do is logically figure out what the next point of data is most likely to be. In the case, for example, it would be `{6: 30}`

what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make scipy.interpolate give an extrapolated result beyond the input range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range)

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered collections, so your "order is always ascending" remark may be a dangerous assumption, since `for key in d` will iterate over the keys however Python sees fit, not in the ordered you created them.

Comment: I meant more in terms of the data, as in each numerically higher key has a numerically higher value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After discussing with you in the Python chat - you're fitting your data to an exponential. This should give a relatively good indicator since you're not looking for long term extrapolation.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def exponential_fit(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    y = np.array([30, 50, 80, 160, 300, 580])
    fitting_parameters, covariance = curve_fit(exponential_fit, x, y)
    a, b, c = fitting_parameters
    
    next_x = 6
    next_y = exponential_fit(next_x, a, b, c)
    
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.plot(np.append(y, next_y), 'ro')
    plt.show()
```

The red dot in the on far right axis shows the next "predicted" point.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use numpy's [polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

```
data = np.array([[1,5], [2,10], [3,15], [4,20], [5,25]])
fit = np.polyfit(data[:,0], data[:,1] ,1) #The use of 1 signifies a linear fit.

fit
[  5.00000000e+00   1.58882186e-15]  #y = 5x + 0

line = np.poly1d(fit)
new_points = np.arange(5)+6

new_points
[ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

line(new_points)
[ 30.  35.  40.  45.  50.]
```

This allows you to alter the degree of the polynomial fit quite easily as the function `polyfit` take thes following arguments `np.polyfit(x data, y data, degree)`. Shown is a linear fit where the returned array looks like `fit[0]*x^n + fit[1]*x^(n-1) + ... + fit[n-1]*x^0` for any degree `n`. The `poly1d` function allows you turn this array into a function that returns the value of the polynomial at any given value `x`.

In general extrapolation without a well understood model will have sporadic results at best.

---

Exponential [curve fitting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

x = np.linspace(0,4,5)
y = func(x, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
yn = y + 0.2*np.random.normal(size=len(x))

fit ,cov = curve_fit(func, x, yn)
fit
[ 2.67217435  1.21470107  0.52942728]         #Variables

y
[ 3.          1.18132948  0.68568395  0.55060478  0.51379141]  #Original data

func(x,*fit)
[ 3.20160163  1.32252521  0.76481773  0.59929086  0.5501627 ]  #Fit to original + noise
```

Comment: thank you good sir, but if you don't mind me asking, what exactly is the 'fit' variable? As in, what does it signify?

Comment: @Crowz - It's a linear model. As Ophion's comment mentions, it's `y = fit[0] * x + fit[1]`.

Comment: would there be a way to imply a model which follows a more exponential path?

Comment: @Crowz You can always fit an exponential to this; however, exponential fitting is inherently more difficult. Please provide a complete example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37172840/5918464) to a related question, as of version 0.17.0 of scipy, there is an option in [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) that allows linear extrapolation. In your case, you could do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import interpolate

>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> y = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
>>> f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, fill_value = "extrapolate")
>>> print(f(6))
30.0
```

Comment: I'd be thrilled if the documentation: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html
actually explained how the extrapolation worked. It doesn't even mention that it's linear, let alone liner based on how many prior or post points (two suffice and would be expected, more would demand a regression).

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is approximately linear you can do a [linear regression](http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/03/linear-regression-with-numpy.html), and then use the results from that regression to calculate the next point, using `y = w[0]*x + w[1]` (keeping the notation from the linked example for *y = mx + b*).

If your data is not approximately linear and you don't have some other theoretical form for a regression, then general extrapolations (using say polynomials or splines) are much less reliable as they can go a bit crazy beyond the known data points.  For example, see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599754/is-there-easy-way-in-python-to-extrapolate-data-points-to-the-future).

Answer (score 0):

Using [`scipy.interpolate.splrep`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html):

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev
>>> d = {1:5, 2:10, 3:15, 4:20, 5:25}
>>> x, y = zip(*d.items())
>>> spl = splrep(x, y, k=1, s=0)
>>> splev(6, spl)
array(30.0)
>>> splev(7, spl)
array(35.0)
>>> int(splev(7, spl))
35
>>> splev(10000000000, spl)
array(50000000000.0)
>>> int(splev(10000000000, spl))
50000000000L
```

See [How to make scipy.interpolate give an extrapolated result beyond the input range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745329/2225682)

Comment: Be careful with using splines to extrapolate. They tend to "overshoot" at the ends.  It's very, very easy to get extrapolation estimates orders of magnitude larger or smaller than your data using splines.  They're great for interpolation, but a very poor choice for extrapolation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a funny one using ***only*** `numpy`, in case you do not want to depend on `scipy`:

```py
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit, polyval
from numpy import interp, ndarray, piecewise


def interp1d(x: ndarray, xp, fp):
    """1D piecewise linear interpolation with linear extrapolation."""
    return piecewise(
        x,
        [x < xp[0], (x >= xp[0]) & (x <= xp[-1]), x > xp[-1]],
        [
            lambda xi: polyval(xi, polyfit(xp[:2], fp[:2], 1)),
            lambda xi: interp(xi, xp, fp),
            lambda xi: polyval(xi, polyfit(xp[-2:], fp[-2:], 1)),
        ],
    )
```

This uses plain [`numpy.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) for interpolation, reverts to a linear [polynomial fit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html) to extrapolate out-of-bounds values, and uses [`numpy.piecewise`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) to string them together.

Instead of `polyval(..., polyfit(...))`, you could also write the linear extrapolation functions yourself, for example:

```py
lambda xi: fp[0] + np.diff(fp[:2]) / np.diff(xp[:2]) * (xi - xp[0])
```

and so on.