# Extrapolating with numpy interp using "left" and "right" parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, interpolation

I am trying to perform linear extrapolation using the `left` and `right` parameters of numpy.interp.

The [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) list these parameters as an "optional float or complex corresponding to fp."

My strategy is as follows, shown for `left`:

`f = numpy.interp(x, xp, fp, left=(x-xp[-1])*(fp[-1]-fp[-2])/(xp[-1]-xp[-2])+fp[-1], right=...)`

This works just fine for single points x, but how do I format `left` if I want to input a **vector for x** (to calculate multiple f's simultaneously)? I have tried inputting the whole vector x into the above expression but received a TypeError.

Comment: In the documentation it mentions that a ValueError is raised if the shapes are incompatible, so your input is likely not of type `np.ndarray`. Could you provide the full traceback?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19406049